# Does `gc` treat Cython's `__dealloc__` similarly to `__del__`?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, cython, cyclic-reference

Python's optional garbage collector [`gc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) ignores cycles that [contain any object with a `__del__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage):

> Changed in version 3.4: Following PEP 442, objects with a `__del__()` method don’t end up in `gc.garbage` anymore.

Cython extension types can have a `__dealloc__` method, but [no `__del__` method](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#finalization-method-dealloc):

> Note: There is no `__del__()` method for extension types.

For the purpose of collecting cycles, is the presence of `__dealloc__` treated by the garbage collector as if a `__del__` method is present? Or is `__dealloc__` invisible to the garbage collector?

Comment: Starting from Python 3.4, objects with the method `__del__` [do not prevent reference cycles from being garbage collected](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/weakref.html#comparing-finalizers-with-del-methods), so even if Cython classes had a `tp_del` slot (which they don't) *and* were on a reference cycle, they would still be garbage collected. So the quotation that mentions PEP 442 may have meant something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the generated C code you can see that Cython generates the destructor in the `tp_dealloc` slot, rather than the `tp_del` slot

```
cdef class B:
    def __dealloc__(self):
        pass
```

generates:

```
static PyTypeObject __pyx_type_5cy_gc_B = {
  PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(0, 0)
  "cy_gc.B", /*tp_name*/
  sizeof(struct __pyx_obj_5cy_gc_B), /*tp_basicsize*/
  0, /*tp_itemsize*/
  __pyx_tp_dealloc_5cy_gc_B, /*tp_dealloc*/

  /* lines omitted */

  0, /*tp_del*/
  0, /*tp_version_tag*/
  #if PY_VERSION_HEX >= 0x030400a1
  0, /*tp_finalize*/
  #endif
};
```

You can easily verify that this is the case for other examples too (e.g. classes with automatically generated `__dealloc__`).

[Therefore, for Python 3.4+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.garbage):

> Starting with Python 3.4, this list should be empty most of the time, except when using instances of C extension types with a non-NULL tp_del slot.

Cython classes should not end up in this list of uncollectable stuff since they don't have `tp_del` defined.

---

For earlier versions of Python I think you're also fine. Mostly because  you still don't have a `__del__` method, but also because [cython automatically generates `tp_traverse` and `tp_clear` functions](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#disabling-cycle-breaking-tp-clear) that should allow Python to break reference cycles involve Cython classes.

You can disable the generation of these `tp_traverse` and `tp_clear` functions. I'm a little unclear on what happens to objects that are in a reference cycle but don't have methods to detect it, or to break it. It's quite likely that they just continue to exist somewhere, but are inaccessible.

---

I think the concern (before Python 3.4) was that `__del__` methods could make an object accessible again:

```
class C:
   def __del__(self):
      global x
      x = self
```

`__dealloc__` is called after the point of no return, and so this isn't allowed (you just get a segmentation fault if you access `x`). Therefore they don't have to be stuck in `gc.garbage` in their indeterminate state.